# increase input type number value by 10 intervals

Tags: html, validation, input

I am using `<input type="number">` where up arrows increase the vale +1 by per click or it goes on when press and hold. But is it possible to increase it by `10, 20, 30 .....` because my input numbers are very in range of `900-20000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using the step attribute you can do it

use `step=10`

```
<input type="number" step=10 />
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nn8nx3xw/)